# Want to know what the +1 in this finite state machine circuit diagram is

Tags: circuit-design, flipflop, diagram

[image]

Can someone tell me what the +1 that goes into the right side J and K is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a signal that's always a logical "1".